# SSRS: How many reports have been sent out within 24hrs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a project that needs to list the reports that have been sent out for the last 24 hours via subscription. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

For example 10 subscriptions were scheduled today but only 8 were successfully sent.

Comment: You want to get a report about subscription execution or reports that the users have executed the last 24 hours?

Comment: @niktrs about report subscription :) thanks in advance

Comment: You should update your question with more info like what's the expected report information

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the list, assuming you are using the name ssrs_dba for your SSRS-database:

```
 SELECT el.UserName, c.name, el.Parameters, el.TimeStart, el.TimeEnd, el.TimeRendering, el.TimeProcessing, el.TimeDataRetrieval, el.Status, el.Format
 FROM ssrs_dba..Catalog c
 INNER JOIN ssrs_dba..ExecutionLog el ON c.ItemID = el.ReportID
 WHERE el.TimeStart > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
 ORDER BY el.TimeStart DESC
```